# SQL use in query for comma separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using a stored procedure and I pass it a string with comma like this:

```
Apple,Banana,Orange
```

I want to use this string inside an `IN` clause, but I don't want to use

```
SELECT value 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@MyStr, ',')
```

How can I generate string that I can use like

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE Fruit IN (@MyStr)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620646/comma-separated-string-using-cte

Comment: @Faisal try splitting the string by delimiter first, then do a subquery search. Let me know if this doesn't work!

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  In order to execute as you wish, you would need DYNAMIC SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a subquery:

```
select *
from mytable
where fruit in (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@MyStr, ','));
```

In older versions of SQL Server, you can use `like`:

```
select *
from mytable
where ',' + @MyStr + ',' like '%,' + fruit + ',%';
```

Comment: its mentioned that i don't want to use string_split

Comment: @Faisal - This answer works given the code in the question so why do you want to make it more difficult and omit a technically sound approach to solving your problem?

Comment: Because STRING_SPLIT is only available as of SQL 2016.  Likely they are running an older server version.  Dynamic SQL would be the way to go as an alternative.

Comment: He gave you a version for older sql that doesn't use string_split.

Comment: i'll try the older version

Comment: yes worked perfect